# Parse PDF files with key - value pair using PDFBox

Tags: java, parsing, pdfbox

I'm currently parsing PDF with `PDFBox` library like this:

```
File f = new File("myFile.pdf");

PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(f);
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFLayoutTextStripper(); //For better printing in console I used a PDFLayoutTextStripper
String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
System.out.println(text);
doc.close();
```

I'm getting a really nice looking pdf. Mine pdf files will have structure like this:

> My super pdf file which is first one of all
>
> someKey1 someValue1
>
> someKey2 someValue2
>
> someKey3 someValue3
>
> ....
>
> someKey1 someValue4
>
> someKey2 someValue5
>
> someKey3 someValue6
>
> ....
>
> some header over here
>
> and here would be my next pair
>
> someKey4 someValue7
>
> ....

Is there any library with could get for me all `values` with e.g. key `someKey1`? Or maybe is there any better solution for parsing PDF in Java?

Comment: And what exactly are your problems isolating the keys and values from the `text` you extracted from the pdf?

Comment: Above example of pdf is very simple, I just wrote it for an idea. In some places my pdf files are more complex. You know maybe better solution for parsing pdf files? My final goal is to create from pdf file a json file.

Comment: As usually text in PDF is merely text without semantics like key/value pairs, software to recognize such key/value pairs must know a specific way to recognize the pairs. In your example that appears pretty easy to implement. For arbitrary *files* which *are more complex* probably a lot more coding (or routines specialized to a concrete type of PDFs) are required. As you are very vague, any response to your question will be very vague or will shift the problem and concentrate on trivial details.